# SqlDataReader[i] datatype

Tags: c#, types, sqldatareader

I'm trying to read out data from a set query row by row and put each record in an object in a list of objects, but I don't know what the datatype is for a single record in SqlDataReader.

```
List<Response> responseList = new List<Response>();
for (int i = 0; reader.Read(); i++) //reader is the SqlDataReader
    responseList.Add(new Response(reader[i]));
```

What datatype do I set the `Response` constructor's parameter as?

```
public Response(IDataRecord r) //what's the data type suppose to be?
{

}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking reader[i].GetType() in your immediate window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reader[i]` is an index to the i-th field of the current record. For example, if your query is

```
SELECT ID, FNAME, LNAME, ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMERS
```

then your loop tries to pass to your function the field ID (i=0) of the first record at the first loop, the field FNAME (i=1) of the second record in the second loop, the field LNAME (i=2) of the third record in the third loop and then the field ADDRESS (i=3) of the fourth record, finally (if you have more than four records retrieved) the code crashes with an out of range exception (i=4 but the columns are just 4)

You need to build an object `Response` and then fill its properties before adding it to the list.
So, still supposing that your object Response has four properties named `ID, FirstName, LastName, Address` then you write

```
List<Response> responseList = new List<Response>();
while(reader.Read()) 
{
      responseList.Add(new Response()
      {
           ID = reader[0].ToString(), 
           FirstName = reader[1].ToString(), 
           LastName = reader[2].ToString(),
           Address = reader[3].ToString()
      };
}
```

Comment: I'm expecting a response with a massive number of rows and 15 columns. Would `reader` be the row array and then `reader[0]` thru `reader[14]`  be the fields?

Comment: Yes, exactly for the fields, but the reader contains just one record, you need to call the Read() method to move it to the next record.

Comment: By the way, this kind of repetitive code (transfer data from db to object and back) is what the ORM are supposed to do. You could spend a little time to learn about them. (I suggest to look at [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/))

Answer (score 1):

At first change your reading condition, secondly you can create a `List <string>` for saving your data.

```
List<string> responseList = new List<string>();

While (reader.Read())
{
  responseList.Add(reader[i]).ToString());
}
```

take in account that now, all fields are saved in the same List (response List), if you wish to save each field separately: (assuming you selecting 3 fields in your sql query)

```
List<string> List1 = new List<string>();
List<string> List2 = new List<string>();
List<string> List3 = new List<string>();
 While (reader.Read())
    {
      List1.Add(reader[0]).ToString());///1st field of select
      List2.Add(reader[1]).ToString());///2nd field of select
      List3.Add(reader[2]).ToString());///3rd field of select

    }
```

Comment: Looking at Steve's answer, setting the properties of Response match each of your field, is a better approach..